# Exponential fit for time series

Tags: fitting, time-series

I'm pretty new to time series, but I'm now practising with it in order to obtain an exponential envelope of my experimental data. I start by importing data, I create the time series, I calculate the upper and lower estimated background (which is a time series itself), then I extract local maxima using `FindPeaks` and finally I try to use `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`, but both of them give the same error: time component is not a valid variable.

On the other hand I don't understand how to use the command `TimeSeriesModelFit` to obtain an exponential fit.

```
t = Take[Transpose[data], 1];
p1 = Take[Transpose[data], -1];
ts1 = TimeSeries[p1, {t}, TemporalRegularity -> True];
eb1ts1 = EstimatedBackground[ts1, 100, Method -> {"SNIP", 1}];
eb2ts1 = -EstimatedBackground[-ts1, 50, Method -> {"SNIP", 1}];
max1 = FindPeaks[eb1ts1, 500];
max2 = FindPeaks[eb2ts1, 500];
FindFit[max1, A Exp[-t/(120 τ)] + B, {A, B, τ}, t]; OR
funfit[t_] := A E^(-(t/(120 τ))) + B;
fitmax = NonlinearModelFit[max1, funfit[t], {τ, A, B}, t, MaxIterations -> 100000]
```

I try this way.

```
{{1/120, -0.0209557}, {1/60, -0.0209557}, {1/40, -0.0209557}, {1/
  30, -0.019019}, {1/24, -0.0209557}, {1/20, -0.019019}, {7/
  120, -0.019019}, {1/15, -0.019019}, {3/40, -0.019019}, {1/
  12, -0.019019}, {11/120, -0.019019}, {1/10, -0.019019}, {13/
  120, -0.019019}, {7/60, -0.019019}, {1/8, -0.019019}, {2/
  15, -0.019019}, {17/120, -0.019019}, {3/20, -0.019019}, {19/
  120, -0.019019}, {1/6, -0.019019}, {7/40, -0.019019}, {11/
  60, -0.019019}, {23/120, -0.019019}, {1/5, -0.019019}, {5/
  24, -0.019019}, {13/60, -0.019019}, {9/40, -0.019019}, {7/
  30, -0.0170823}, {29/120, -0.0170823}, {1/4, -0.0170823}, {31/
  120, -0.0170823}, {4/15, -0.0170823}, {11/40, -0.019019}, {17/
  60, -0.0170823}, {7/24, -0.0170823}, {3/10, -0.0170823}, {37/
  120, -0.0170823}, {19/60, -0.019019}, {13/40, -0.019019}, {1/
  3, -0.019019}, {41/120, -0.019019}, {7/20, -0.019019}, {43/
  120, -0.019019}, {11/30, -0.019019}, {3/8, -0.019019}, {23/
  60, -0.019019}, {47/120, -0.019019}, {2/5, -0.019019}, {49/
  120, -0.019019}, {5/12, -0.019019}, {17/40, -0.019019}, {13/
  30, -0.019019}, {53/120, -0.019019}, {9/20, -0.019019}, {11/
  24, -0.019019}, {29/60, -0.0170823}, {59/120, -0.0170823}, {1/
  2, -0.019019}, {61/120, -0.019019}, {31/60, -0.019019}, {21/
  40, -0.019019}, {11/20, -0.0170823}, {67/120, -0.0170823}, {17/
  30, -0.019019}, {23/40, -0.019019}, {7/12, -0.019019}, {71/
  120, -0.019019}, {37/60, -0.019019}, {5/8, -0.019019}, {19/
  30, -0.019019}, {77/120, -0.019019}, {2/3, -0.019019}, {27/
  40, -0.019019}, {41/60, -0.019019}, {83/120, -0.019019}, {7/
  10, -0.019019}, {17/24, -0.019019}, {43/60, -0.019019}, {29/
  40, -0.019019}, {11/15, -0.019019}, {89/120, -0.019019}, {3/
  4, -0.0209557}, {91/120, -0.0209557}, {23/30, -0.0209557}, {31/
  40, -0.0209557}, {47/60, -0.0209557}, {19/24, -0.0209557}, {4/
  5, -0.019019}, {97/120, -0.019019}, {49/60, -0.019019}, {33/
  40, -0.019019}, {5/6, -0.019019}, {101/120, -0.019019}, {17/
  20, -0.0209557}, {103/120, -0.0209557}, {9/10, -0.0228924}, {109/
  120, -0.0228924}, {11/12, -0.0228924}, {37/40, -0.0228924}, {14/
  15, -0.0209557}}
```

This is a plot of the overall data (position as a function of time=[image: oscillation of a pendulum]

I'm interested in the damping phase, so in the second phase.
The first phase is very short and cannot be even perceived in the overall plot.
I would like to obtain an exponential envelop which show how fast the maximum oscillation amplitude goes to zero with respect to time.
As you can see, the oscillation shows some beats; I would like to be able to select the local maxima of each beat and to "interpolate" those decreasing maxima with the best exponential.

Hello Hugh, I would like to follow your path in using NonlinearModelFit, but I don't know how to guess the initial parameter values. Is there a guideline to follow? Any practical hint you can provide in order to get closer to the correct ones? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes it much easier to read.  But there are only 4 distinct (and equally spaced) y-values.  Is this a time series with just 4 distinct states?

Comment: I don't understand how you are defining your phases. If there is just one interval you are interested in please extract that from the data and add a further plot. Then give us a clear description of what you wish to extract from this interval. Possibilities could be frequency, damping ratio, envelope etc

Comment: Could you update the pastebin code so that I can be easily imported in Mathematica? For example using `data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/M03RMCJk", "List"]`.

Comment: sure, I do it now.

Comment: Please check here:https://pastebin.com/XKQBCNuX

Comment: I must have been unclear. The first thing when trying to answer your question, is to manage to import the data. For now, when I go `data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/M03RMCJk", "List"]` from my notebook, I cannot import it properly (try it yourself and you'll see what I mean). I was asking if you could arrange that, either but changing the style of the uploaded data, or by providing a command to import it straightforwardly.

Comment: I'm sorry. Please try with: data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/M03RMCJk", "Table"]

Comment: Your new last paragraph should be a comment.  We will need all your data to get the maxima of the beats. Please can you put them in a new pastebin.  I think you need some sort of envelope function. This can be done but we need your data.

Comment: Unfortunately pastebin is not big enough. Could you suggest a different transfer method? It is 25MB text file.

Comment: sorry to be so late, but I finally realised I could share the whole data using dropbox: here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf15lj483mnav48/tx1.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I have imported your data and this is a plot

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The data is sampled over only a few quantisation levels of your analog to digital converter. You could do with some analogue gain before the converter to give you better resolution. However, that has nothing to do with Mathematica. The data is not an exponential but an oscillating function with possibly an exponential envelope. It has a mean offset.  Let's fit an appropriate function.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  m + a E^(b t) Cos[ ω t + ϕ], {{m, -0.02}, {a, 
    1.5 10^-20}, {b, 0.0100}, {ω, 2.9}, ϕ}, t]
```

This is a nonlinear model so we have to make good initial guesses. I played around a bit to find good estimates.

Now we plot the data and the fitted curve

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[t], {t, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a reasonable fit. More data would see if this model is any good.

The details of the fitted parameters can be found from

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is the output of a video tracking of a pendulum in a chain. And I've extracted a very short part of the motion.

Comment: I think it is too short to be any use. Can you see an exponential in this? You need to give us much more data. Consider using pastebin and giving us the link.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M03RMCJk

Comment: I provided data corresponding to a 20s recording, which is very short. But anyway the problem I face is very basic. Mathematica FindFit or NonlinearFit complains about the kind of data I provide. As an example this is the error I get: General::ivar: {1/120,1/60,1/40,1/30,1/24,1/20,7/120,1/15,3/40,1/12,11/120,1/10,13/120,7/60,1/8,2/15,17/120,3/20,19/120,1/6,7/40,11/60,23/120,1/5,5/24,13/60,9/40,7/30,29/120,1/4,31/120,4/15,11/40,17/60,7/24,3/10,37/120,19/60,13/40,1/3,41/120,7/20,43/120,11/30,3/8,23/60,47/120,2/5,49/120,5/12,<<765191>>} is not a valid variable.

Comment: Hi Hugh, I really appreciate your help. Indeed it is an oscillating function with an exponential envelop. I'm exactly looking for this envelop, when the oscillation amplitude stop growing and start decreasing.

Comment: I think we need to see a plot of your complete data set so that we can see what you are trying to do. Can you add this to your question.  I feel I am working in the dark at the moment.

Comment: The error message would suggest that a variable was mistakenly assigned to the actual data. As others have noted, there are perhaps other issues with this.

Comment: One gets more stable results (i.e., less dependent on starting values) if `Exp[a + b t]` is used rather than `a Exp[b t]`.